# How to solve for x if it is on the top of the fraction?

Tags: fractions

so you have the equation: $$0.0850= \frac{x}{0.125} $$
How do you solve for x?

Comment: Multiply with the denominator.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Use the fact that $\frac{x}a\cdot a=x$. (That’s one of the nicest places for $x$ to be, if you have to solve for it.)

Answer (score 0):

You must multiply both sides of your equation by .125 then you have
.0850*.125=x.

Answer (score 0):

From
$.0850= \dfrac{x}{.125} 
$,
multiply both sides by
$.125$
to get
$$(.0850)\times(.125)
= \dfrac{x}{.125} .125
=x
$$